# How to change UI in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome

After using Ubuntu for a while, I realised that Ubuntu GNOME is rich in graphical interfaces, which consumes a lot of resources from my laptop, which is kind of old.

What i want to do is to switch to Xubuntu if it's possible or any other suggested UI that is simpler in graphical terms.

Is it possible and how to do it?

P.S suggestions of other interfaces are welcome!

Comment: My favorite is the MATE desktop environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: Oh sorry, didn't read carefully. I was thinking of the normal Ubuntu.
Most of the steps should apply though, as Unity is based on GNOME 3.*

**How To Install XFCE alongside Unity (the enviornment that comes with Ubuntu)**

It's recommended to add another user so data doesn't corrupt. (Skip if you don't want to)

Open System Settings (unity-control-center) and click User Accounts. Click the *Unlock* button on the top right and type in your password as needed. Then, click the + button on the bottom left and select Administrator. Then, choose a Username and Name for the account.

Log out of the account you are in right now and Log In to the account you just made.

**Install XFCE**

It's recommended to update your sources.
Open Terminal with *Ctrl + Alt + T* and type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, install XFCE!

```
sudo apt-get install -y xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

Log out, click the Ubuntu logo over the account name, and click XFCE.

**Another way**

You can download Xubuntu from the official website, [here](http://xubuntu.org/)

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Switch on your computer.

`Press` and `hold` the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

Press `Return` and your machine will begin the boot process.

Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

One of the options will be `Network`. Press `Return` with this option highlighted.

Other of the options  will be `Drop to root shell prompt`. Press `Return` with this option highlighted.

In the terminal run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(ubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```